# How to sort array of objects according to a property of the object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an Array of objects. each object in the Array has a property called "priorityTag"

I would like to sort the Array ascendingly according the "priorityTag".
So, I wrote the below posted code, but it does not work.

please let me know how to sort the Array according to the "priorityTag"

**Note**: priortyTag is a property in of the object that is contained in the Array. in other words, each element in the Array is an object, and each object has a alot of properties, but one of These properties is "PriorityTag"

I want to sort the Array according to the "priorityTag"

**code**:

```
sortFeaturesPerPriority2(arr) {
logger.debug('[sortFeaturesPerPriority2]: arr:', arr);

 arr.sort((a, b) => a.priorityTag - b.priorityTag);
 }
```

Comment: what is in priorityTag ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript - I guess this is what you were looking for

Comment: @Logar i edited my question

Comment: What you've got there should work provided the priority tag is a number

Comment: I meant, what is the type of the variable ? as @AndrewBone said, this code should work if you are working with numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort array of objects by string property value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript)

Comment: I guess it would hav to return the sorted array at the minute I think it's just lost once the function is done.

Comment: @AndrewBone what do you mean ? Array.prototype.sort() is a synchronous function, mutating your array. So your array should be sorted if you look for it right after the function call

Comment: even though arr is a parameter sent in with the function sortFeaturesPerPriority2(arr)? I'm not 100% on how that works

Comment: In your case, yes it should still work, arrays are passed by reference. Just to make sure, Can you try to log your array right after `arr.sort(..` and right after the call of `sortFeaturesPerPriority2` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming priority tag is a number then this looks right.  I tried with those code and it ordered them

```
const arr = [
  {priorityTag: 1},
  {priorityTag: 5},
  {priorityTag: 0},
  {priorityTag: 2},
  {priorityTag: 6},
]
arr.sort( (a,b) => a.priorityTag - b.priorityTag ); // 0,1,2,5,6
```

If the priorityTag is a string then I would just use the following.  This actually will work for both strings and numbers assuming you're ok how the greater than works with strings by default.

```
arr.sort( (a,b) => a.priorityTag > b.priorityTag );
```

Comment: I believe the comparison function must return an integer, not sure what the behaviour will be with a boolean, but I remember I had troubles using a boolean return type

Comment: @logar hmm good point. I didn't realize that actually. I guess the boolean is just being casted to an integer implicitly?  Seems to be working for this simple example at least, but I'll keep an eye out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can use a prototype I've done

```
/**
 * ARRAY PROTOTYPE SORT BY
 * Used to sort an array by object field
 * @param {String} field
 */
Array.prototype.sortBy = function (field = '') {
    this.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a[field] == b[field] ? 0 : +( a[field] > b[field]) || -1;
    });
};
```

You can use like this :

```
let array = [{name: 'Jonh', age: 71}, {name: 'Tracey', age: 58}];
array.sortBy('age');
console.log(array); // Display [ { name: 'Tracey', age: 58 }, { name: 'Jonh', age: 71 } ]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're having `integers like` variables inside `priorityTag`s, you need to parse them before sorting

```
sortFeaturesPerPriority2(arr) {
    logger.debug('[sortFeaturesPerPriority2]: arr:', arr);

     arr.sort(({priorityTag: p1}, {priorityTag: p2}) => parseInt(p1) - parseInt(p2));
 }
```

If you cannot parse your priorityTags into numeric values (let's say you have `priorityTag == 'a'` or `priorityTag == 'b'`), you can look at the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) provided by @sander in the comments

### Edit

Not really answering OP's question, but here is a neat way of defining all kinds of sorts by properties :

```
const arr = [
  {priorityTag: 'a'}, 
  {priorityTag: 'e'},
  {priorityTag: 'd'},
  {priorityTag: 'b'},
  {priorityTag: 'c'}, 
];

const numericSort = prop => ({[prop]: a}, {[prop]: b}) => a - b;
const alphaSort = prop => ({[prop]: a}, {[prop]: b}) => a < b ? -1 : 1;
const weirdCustomSort = prop => ({[prop]: a}, {[prop]: b}) => {
  const elements = ['a','e','b','d','c'];
  const aIndex = ~elements.indexOf(a) ? elements.indexOf(a) : elements.length;
  const bIndex = ~elements.indexOf(b) ? elements.indexOf(b) : elements.length;
  return aIndex - bIndex;
};

const compareBy = prop => sortFunc => sortFunc(prop)

console.log([...arr].sort(compareBy('priorityTag')(alphaSort)))
console.log([...arr].sort(compareBy('priorityTag')(numericSort)))
console.log([...arr].sort(compareBy('priorityTag')(weirdCustomSort)))
```